# How come when I import my package X.* - java will throw an error but if I specify the class directly (example: X.Linked_List) there is no error

Tags: java

When my second line is Linked_List.Linked_List; there are no issues, but if I 
use the code below I get the following error.

bad source file: ./Linked_List.java
    file does not contain class Linked_List
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.

```
import java.util.*;
import Linked_List.*;

public class Remove_Dups {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] myArray = {1,1,23,44,99,223,1,5,5};
        Linked_List myList = new Linked_List(myArray);
        myList.remove_duplicates();
        myList.print();
    }   
}
```

My directory has the following 
Linked_List Remove_Dups.class Remove_Dups.java

Within the Linked_List directory I have the following,
Linked_List.class Node.class

Here is the beginning of Linked_List.java file

```
package Linked_List;
import java.util.HashSet;

    public class Linked_List {
    Node head;

    public Linked_List(int[] dataArray) { 
        int i = 1;
        head = new Node(dataArray[0]);
        Node current = head;

        while (i < dataArray.length) {
            Node next = new Node(dataArray[i]);
            current.next = next;
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }   
   }
```

Comment: 1. Respect the Java naming conventions: classes never contain any underscore, packages are all lowercase. 2. Respect the hierarchy. If a class `Foo` is in the package `com.bar`, then its Java source file must be named `Foo.java`, and must be located in a directory `com/bar`.

Comment: Can you show the content of your `Linked_List.java` file and the directory tree that contains it?

Comment: I made the appropriate edits to give more info now